# Mysql count when comparing date laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

my Query-

```
 $today = date("Y-m-d");
 $Reminder = Status::where('change_status_to', '=', $today)->count();
```

I want to get reminder if the date is today or the date 1 day ago or the date crosses today's date.

Comment: than put three condition using OR

Comment: Whenver i use orWhere, if i supposed to get reminder 1 i get then 3.. the count() increases that case :(

Comment: can you give a full query and sample data and what you get and what you want

Comment: We have no idea what your data looks like, we have no idea what the output should be. How do you expect us to help you this way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use this if you want count Status from yesterday and today. You only needs Carbon.

```
$reminder = Status::whereBetween('change_status_to', [Carbon::now()->subDay(), Carbon::now()])->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want all statuses that are newer than yesterday?

To compare dates, you can use the [Carbon library](http://carbon.nesbot.com/), wich is included in Laravel.

```
$Reminder = Status::whereBetween('change_status_to', [\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(-1)->startOfDay(), \Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])->count();
```

Comment: Better use subDay() instead of addDays(-1).

Comment: Internally, it's the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$Reminder = Status::whereDate('change_status_to', $today)->count();
```